# save or update problem

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, ejb-3.0

We have an application which has a swing client and java app on the server (jboss.4.2.1.GA) side. We are using ejb3. 
In our application at some point we are successfuly creating an invoice and show it to the user but when user wants to chage the invoice we get the following error. After reloading the invoice user can be able to change the invoice without any error.
The invoice creation code, invoice change and full error stack are as following:

```
public Invoice createInvoice(String invoiceNo, CreateInvoiceGroupTemplate template, Collection serviceCalculations)
        throws Exception
{
    manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

    if (glDao.isInvoiceNoInUse(manager, invoiceNo))
        throw new NonUniqueInvoiceNoException(invoiceNo);

    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.setNo(invoiceNo);
    invoice.setInvoiceDate(template.getMinimumInvoiceDate());
    Date paymentDay = findInvoicePaymentDay(template);
    invoice.setPaymentDate(paymentDay);
    invoice.setFormBeginDate(template.getFormBeginDate());
    invoice.setFormEndDate(template.getFormEndDate());

    Currency currency = new Currency();
    currency.setId(template.getCurrencyId());
    invoice.setCurrency((Currency) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, currency));

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId(template.getCustomerId());
    invoice.setCustomer((Customer) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, customer));

    if (template.getRepresentativeId() > 0)
    {
        Representative representative = new Representative();
        representative.setId(template.getRepresentativeId());
        invoice.setRepresentative((Representative) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, representative));
    }

    if (template.getAccountingGroupId() != 0)
    {
        AccountingGroup accountingGroup = new AccountingGroup();
        accountingGroup.setId(template.getAccountingGroupId());
        invoice.setAccountingGroup((AccountingGroup) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, accountingGroup));
    }

    if (template.getAirlineGroupId() > 0)
    {
        AirlineGroup airlineGroup = new AirlineGroup();
        airlineGroup.setId(template.getAirlineGroupId());
        invoice.setAirlineGroup((AirlineGroup) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, airlineGroup));
    }

    if (template.getAirportId() != 0)
    {
        Airport airport = new Airport();
        airport.setId(template.getAirportId());
        invoice.setAirport((Airport) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, airport));
    }

    //automatically create new address based on the last invoice for this customer and representative
    InvoiceAddress oldInvoiceAddress = glDao.findAddressForLastInvoice(manager, invoice);
    if (oldInvoiceAddress != null)
    {
        InvoiceAddress invoiceAddress = (InvoiceAddress) oldInvoiceAddress.copyEntity();
        invoice.setInvoiceAddress(invoiceAddress);
    }

    HashMap invoiceDetails = new HashMap();
    String key = "";

    try
    {
        Collection mappings = invoice.getInvoiceMappings();
        InvoiceMapping invoiceMapping = null;
        ServiceCalculation serviceCalculation = null;
        ServiceCalculation refreshedServiceCalculation = null;
        Iterator itr = serviceCalculations.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            serviceCalculation = (ServiceCalculation) itr.next();
            invoiceMapping = new InvoiceMapping();

            refreshedServiceCalculation = (ServiceCalculation) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, serviceCalculation);
            refreshedServiceCalculation.setInvoiced(true);
            refreshedServiceCalculation.setVatRateModified(serviceCalculation.isVatRateModified());

            if (refreshedServiceCalculation instanceof CalculatedService)
                invoiceMapping.setCalculatedService((CalculatedService) refreshedServiceCalculation);
            else if (refreshedServiceCalculation instanceof CalculatedRoyalty)
                invoiceMapping.setCalculatedRoyalty((CalculatedRoyalty) refreshedServiceCalculation);
            else if (refreshedServiceCalculation instanceof CalculatedCommission)
                invoiceMapping.setCalculatedCommission((CalculatedCommission) refreshedServiceCalculation);

            mappings.add(invoiceMapping);

            serviceCalculation = (ServiceCalculation) dao.saveOrUpdateEntity(manager, refreshedServiceCalculation);

            key = createKey(serviceCalculation);
            processInvoiceDetail(invoiceDetails, key, serviceCalculation);
        }

        ArrayList processedInvoiceDetails = clearInvoiceDetails(invoiceDetails.values());
        invoice.getInvoiceDetails().addAll(processedInvoiceDetails);

        updateExchangeRate(invoice);

        invoice = (Invoice) dao.saveOrUpdateEntity(manager, invoice);

        glDao.initializeInvoice(invoice);
    }
    catch (ApplicationException exc)
    {
        logger.error(exc);
        ctx.setRollbackOnly();
        throw exc;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logger.error(exc);
        ctx.setRollbackOnly();
        throw exc;
    }

    return invoice;
}

public ServerResponse synchronizeInvoice(GridData gridData) throws Exception
{
    ServerResponse response = new ServerResponse();

    try
    {
        manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

        Invoice loadedInvoice = null;

        //boolean invoiceRemoved=false;

        Collection entitiesToRemove = gridData.getGarbageData();
        Iterator itr = entitiesToRemove.iterator();
        Object temp = null;
        Invoice invoice = null;
        InvoiceDetail invoiceDetail = null;
        while (itr.hasNext())
        {
            temp = itr.next();

            if (temp instanceof Invoice)
            {
                invoice = (Invoice) temp;
                loadedInvoice = (Invoice) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, invoice);
                if (loadedInvoice.getStatus() == Invoice.INVOICE_FINALIZED
                        || loadedInvoice.getStatus() == Invoice.INVOICE_CANCELLED)
                    throw new InvoiceFinalizedException();
                else
                {
                    updateMappingsAsNotInvoiced(invoice);
                    dao.removeEntity(manager, invoice);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //instance of invoice detail
                invoiceDetail = (InvoiceDetail) temp;
                dao.removeEntity(manager, invoiceDetail);
            }
        }

        Collection updatedEntity = gridData.getNewUpdatedBuffer();
        updatedEntity.addAll(gridData.getUpdatedBuffer());

        itr = updatedEntity.iterator();
        if (itr.hasNext())
        {
            temp = itr.next();
            invoice = (Invoice) temp;
            loadedInvoice = (Invoice) dao.findByPrimaryKey(manager, invoice);
            if(loadedInvoice!=null)
            {
                if ((loadedInvoice.getStatus() == Invoice.INVOICE_FINALIZED && invoice.getStatus() != Invoice.INVOICE_CANCELLED)
                        || loadedInvoice.getStatus() == Invoice.INVOICE_CANCELLED)
                    throw new InvoiceFinalizedException();
                else
                {
                    if (invoice.getStatus() == Invoice.INVOICE_FINALIZED)
                    {
                        JMSHelper helper = new JMSHelper();
                        helper.sendMessage("queue/InvoiceFinalizeEvent", invoice);
                        finalizeInvoice(invoice);
                    }
                    else if (invoice.getStatus() == Invoice.INVOICE_CANCELLED)
                    {
                        JMSHelper helper = new JMSHelper();
                        helper.sendMessage("queue/InvoiceFinalizeEvent", invoice);
                        cancelInvoice(invoice);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        updateExchangeRate(invoice);
                        invoice=(Invoice) dao.saveOrUpdateEntity(manager, invoice);
                    }

                    response.addData(invoice);
                }
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            Iterator synchronizedData=gridData.getSynchBuffer().iterator();
            if(synchronizedData.hasNext())
            {
                invoice = (Invoice) synchronizedData.next();
                response.addData(invoice);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ApplicationException exc)
    {
        ctx.setRollbackOnly();
        response.addException(exc);
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        ctx.setRollbackOnly();
        throw exc;
    }

    return response;
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/type/AbstractComponentType;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1880)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1610)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:52)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:425)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:413)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:310)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:547)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1846)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1846)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.InvocationResponse.readExternal(InvocationResponse.java:122)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:239)
at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:133)
at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:120)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedRead(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:943)
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:584)
at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1550)
at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:530)
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:62)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.aspects.security.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:72)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessRemoteProxy.invoke(StatelessRemoteProxy.java:103)
at $Proxy5.synchronizeInvoice(Unknown Source)
at com.celebi.ikarus.gl.bdo.GLBusinessDelegator.synchronizeInvoice(GLBusinessDelegator.java:116)
at com.celebi.ikarus.gl.window.WInvoice.saveButtonPressed(WInvoice.java:303)
at com.celebi.ikarus.main.component.toolbar.MainToolBar$5.actionPerformed(MainToolBar.java:129)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be serializing classes created by Hibernate directly to your client, since you are getting Hibernate artifacts sent.  This is what causes your NoClassDefFound error.

You should use a value object of your own creation and convert the Hibernate results to those objects.  This will rid you of hidden links to Hibernate specific classes.

Answer (score 2):

You have one or more entity relationships defined with a fetch = FetchType.LAZY.
The associated entity that that is part of this relationship is being replaced with an AbstractComponentType.

Since the class org.hibernate.type.AbstractComponentType is not included in the JBoss client jars, the JVM is throwing a ClassNotFoundException.

So, to solve this problem you can change the FetchType to EAGER or you can make sure the relationship is initialized in your session bean before sending responses to the client.

(You may also add to your class path a jar containing the AbstractComponentType class, as long as the client will not attempt to access the entity that is being replaced with this AbstractComponentType --I would not recommend this last alternative. )

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is that ServerResponse is being filled with data that references org/hibernate/type/AbstractComponentType, and the hibernate classes are not on the classpath of the swing client. You could add the hibernate classes to the client classpath, but more likely that you are sending back an object that is heavier and contains more references than you think.

There isn't enough information about that class and how your invoices are made in general to know more, but the exception indicates that that is the core problem.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace indicates that the class "org.hibernate.type.AbstractComponentType" is not available in the client when you try to send the Invoice instance to the server while saving.

There is either a mistake in the class definition somewhere or you must add the hibernate JARs to the client's classpath.